# Jmeter - View Results In Table - Cannot Identify Different Thread Loops

Tags: loops, jmeter, listener

My Environment: JMeter v2.12, remote Oracle 12, JDK 7

I am using the View Results in Table to view some results of a test.

I have some samplers in my Thread Group that create some XML and submit them to a web service.  I am using the 'View Results In Table' listener to view the results, however with many loops it is getting difficult to spot which thread loop the detail is referencing.

My setup is as follows:

```
Thread Group-->No. of Users: 1, Loop: 8000
-CSV Data Set Config: (provides a csv file with variables for XML)
-Beanshell Sampler: (to create XML, sourcing values from the .csv)
-Beanshell Sampler: (adds SOAP header to XML instance)
-SOAP/XML-RPC Request: (injects SOAP message to webservice)
-View Results In Table
```

Essentially because my thread group has number of users = 1, it is getting difficult to spot which loop a particular sampler (displayed in the View Results In Table listener) refers to - please see example screenshot below where I had the Loop Count set to 3.

[image]

As you can see in the screenshot - the 'Thread Name' column displays in the format 'Thread Group Name 1-1'.

I was hoping it would indicate from the 1-1 value (e.g. 1-3 might indicate the 3rd loop) which loop the different samplers are associated with.  This isn't a problem when there are only 3 loops specified, but if I have 8000 (which is what I've got to test) - identifying which results are for which loop is going to be a problem.

So - finally - my question.

Is there any way for the results to display an incremented Thread Group name to reflect which loop is which when my No. of Users = 1, and Loop Count = many?

Many thanks!

sqeeky

Comment: Cheers to both for responding - really helped me out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Amend your Sampler name to include

- [__threadNum()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) function
- [__counter()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__counter) function

I.e.

```
MySampler - Thread: ${__threadNum}  Loop: ${__counter(TRUE,)}
```

So you'll receive the following (assumes 3 threads and 3 loops):

[image: Dynamic Sampler Name with Functions]

See [How to Use JMeter Functions](http://blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-functions-part-iii) post series for extra information on above and other useful JMeter Functions.

Answer (score 0):

When using loops, there are 2 samplers  you really should care about.  Firstly, the "Once Only Controller".   Secondly, the "Counter".  You can use the "Counter" to increment a number every time it gets called and then reference that number from the sampler name.   Just name your samplers like "HTTPSampler - Does Whatever : ${__threadNum} - ${numSubitem}"

```
int numSubitem = 10;
int maxCounter = numSubitem - 1;
vars.put("numSubitem",Integer.toString(numSubitem));
vars.put("maxCounter",Integer.toString(maxCounter));
```